# What are the current travel restrictions on individuals entering the United States from regions affected by Covid-19?

Tags: usa, health, covid-19, event-based-effects

This community wiki explains the current restrictions by the United States of America on the entry of individuals who may pose a risk of transmission of the SARS-Cov2, the virus which causes the Covid-19 disease.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This answer currently lists **nationwide entry restrictions imposed by the United States federal (national) government** in response to COVID-19. There used to be state-specific restrictions (such as for Hawaii) but those have been replaced with nationwide rules by November 8th 2021.

Travelers who do not already have a **valid visa and will need one for their planned travel should note that the US Embassies and Consulates are open at this time for limited services.** Check the website of the consulate in your country for more information.

---

**Vaccination requirement**

As of May 12, 2023, there is no requirement to be vaccinated against COVID-19 before traveling to the US.

- Lifting of air entry restrictions:

  - White House [announcement](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/statements-releases/2023/05/01/the-biden-administration-will-end-covid-19-vaccination-requirements-for-federal-employees-contractors-international-travelers-head-start-educators-and-cms-certified-facilities/)
  - The revocation of the vaccination requirement for nonimmigrants entering by air: [Proclamation 10575](https://www.federalregister.gov/d/2023-10406)
  - [CDC's page](https://www.cdc.gov/quarantine/order-safe-travel.html) on the terminated order
- Lifting of land entry restrictions:

  - DHS [announcement](https://www.dhs.gov/news/2023/05/01/dhs-statement-lifting-title-19-requirements)
  - US-Canada land border restriction termination [notice](https://www.federalregister.gov/d/2023-09948)
  - US-Mexico land border restriction termination [notice](https://www.federalregister.gov/d/2023-09949)

However, a [separate requirement](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/News/visas-news/changes-to-vaccination-requirements-for-immigrant-visa-applicants.html) as part of the existing medical exam requirement, means that new immigrants must still receive the COVID vaccine prior to receiving such a visa.

---

**COVID-19 test requirement**

There is no requirement to do a COVID-19 test before traveling to the US.

The requirement for a COVID-19 test for people flying from China was lifted on March 10, 2023 at 3pm EST.

- The [rescission](https://www.cdc.gov/quarantine/china-proof-negative-test.html) of the China testing requirement