# Does the USA Coronavirus 2019-nCoV travel ban in China include Taiwan?

Tags: china, event-based-effects, taiwan, travel-ban, covid-19

I plan on traveling to Taiwan soon. Trying to understand the scope of the travel ban. Flights have not been cancelled.

Comment: What "travel ban" are you talking about? There is no "ban" on people traveling to China, although there is an advisory to avoid travel to China. There is a ban on foreigners (except US permanent residents, and immediate family of US citizens and permanent residents) who have been to Mainland China in the previous 14 days from entering the US. Is that what you are asking about, about whether Taiwan is included in the area?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert The US has "banned" the vast majority of people on the planet from travelling from China to the USA.

Comment: @Doc: somehow I had missed that story, which is separate from the State Department travel advisory issued last week.  For those who want more details, [see here](https://www.cnn.com/2020/02/02/us/coronavirus-us-travel-restrictions/index.html).

Answer (score 7):

The current Corona Virus related travel bans affect mainland China only, NOT including Hong Kong and Taiwan.

For the purposes of travel advice, the Department Of State treats China, Hong Kong and Taiwan as 3 separate entities.  At the time of writing, the currently threat levels for these 3 are :

[Taiwan](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/Taiwan.html) - Level 1 : Exercise normal precautions (Last Updated January 2019)

[Hong Kong](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/HongKong.html) - Level 2 : Exercise Increased Caution (Last updated January 31, 2020 and specifically referecing CoronaVirus)

[China](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/China.html) - Level 4 : Do Not Travel (Last Updated February 2, 2020)

Answer (score -1):

The Department of State says not to travel to "China." Of course, Taiwan is part of China, according to both the PRC and one major political faction in Taiwan. Since State does not officially recognize Taiwan, it's hard to say whether that policy includes the island.

https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/traveladvisories/traveladvisories/china-travel-advisory.html

On the other hand, their Taiwan page says to exercise normal precautions only.

https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/Taiwan.html

EDIT: another answer says Taiwan is NOT included: [What are the current travel restrictions on individuals entering the United States from regions affected by novel coronavirus?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/153131/what-are-the-current-travel-restrictions-on-individuals-entering-the-united-stat)

Edit the second: The CDC is now (4 February 2020) specifically excluding Taiwan (and Macau and Hong Kong) from no-travel recommendations: https://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/destinations/traveler/none/china#travel-notices

Comment: Note also that the State Department's [map of travel advisories](https://travelmaps.state.gov/TSGMap/) colors Taiwan differently from mainland China.

Comment: This is incorrect.  The Dept of State treats China, Hong Kong and Taiwan as 3 separate countries.

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder check his answer above?

Comment: @Doc To be technical you were right in the answer when you said "entities" rather than "countries".