# Does the U.S. novel coronavirus ban affect those who've been to areas claimed by China but administered by India?

Tags: usa, india, china, health, covid-19

Per [What are the current travel restrictions on individuals entering the United States from regions affected by novel coronavirus?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/153131/11329) (emphasis added):

> The 14-day rule does not apply the Special Administrative Regions of Hong Kong and Macau. It **does apply to the disputed province of Tibet**. It does not apply to Taiwan, the Republic of China, which is claimed by the People's Republic of China but is not functionally a part of that country.

There are areas of Tibet (mainland China) that are claimed by China, but administered by India, such as the state of Arunachal Pradesh and parts of the Union Territory of Ladakh southwest of the Line of Control.

Are those who visited these areas (of India) (of China) affected by the U.S. coronavirus travel restrictions?

Also, are they considered to be lying if they've visited one of these areas and have only claimed to have visited India?

Comment: If the regions are controlled by India and as such administered by India and as such give you a India stamp in your passport, I would have thought they are not affected by the 14 day rule and that travel can happen normally.

Comment: Best bet is email or phone CBP. Wouldn’t give an answer you receive here on such a fast changing topic much weight.

Comment: This isn't a sensible question. Areas of Tibet administered by India are part of India from the US point of view, and if they didn't they would be part of "the disputed province of Tibet".

Comment: If this question is missing detail, it would be nice if I knew what details need to be added or what needs to be clarified.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.