# Where can we find frequently updated details about travel/entry restrictions due to Coronavirus (nCoV-19)?

Tags: air-travel, international-travel, covid-19, travel-ban

Due to the outbreak of nCoV-19 (Novel Coronavirus) many Countries have imposed several entry restrictions. But these are quite confusing for a lot of people. Some countries allow transit through parts of China (like Shanghai) but some restrict transit even through Hong Kong/Macau. Philippines restricted passengers coming from Taiwan too, but I think that that was later changed.

Where can one find a list of such restrictions for all the countries, ideally a source that is updated frequently

Comment: Are you only limited in authority-issued travel restrictions, or also in cancelled/suspended flight/train/ferry routes?

Comment: Some countries don't have a nice webpage for that kind of information, this is why I posted [What percentage of international flights departing from Manila are cancelled due to Duterte's lockdown on Metro Manila from 2020-03-15 to 2020-04-14?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/154940/1810).

Comment: @gerrit The more information the merrier!

Comment: @JoErNanO Just want to give some feedback regarding [my question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/156677/66312). IATA does not seem to have the updated information for a few countries (e.g. Bulgaria). I called the Embassy of Romania yesterday and they said that only the transit to home is accepted, but they don't let you stay in the country. Hungary does not accept non-nationals, without a special reason either. There are other countries from that list with similar missing data.

Comment: @IonicăBizău Excellent. Thanks for the research. Can you please update the answer below to incorporate this information? As you can see it is hard to give reliable answers to the real questions we are all asking ourselves related to the impact of Covid on travel, as policies vary, are changing rapidly, and are updated at seemingly random intervals. Hence why it is hard for us to do our QA job on this site right now. For these reasons we need a canonical providing a single point-of-entry for all information, that we keep updated as best we can.

Comment: @JoErNanO I think that one who travels should first search information published by their own country regarding traveling to the country where they want to travel. For instance, in my specific case, [here are the rules published by Romania about Bulgaria](https://www.mae.ro/travel-conditions/3677). While IATA says: the rule is not aplicable to EU citizens, the Romanian page says the rule is not applied to EU citizens that are involved in working for infrastructure and security of Bulgaria.

Comment: Also, the `https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/<COUNTRY>.html` pages is a good resource in English about the rules of each country. For [Bulgaria the emitted this alert](https://bg.usembassy.gov/novel-coronavirus-covid-19-information/) that is listed among [the other alerts](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/Bulgaria.html).

Comment: @JoErNanO Just another update: my flight to Bulgaria was cancelled just a couple of hours before, since Sofia entered in quarantine. On the other side, the Embassy of Romania talked with the authorities to allow me to transit Hungary (even tho the rules were that no transit was accepted in my case). So [I have arrived safely in Romania](https://www.facebook.com/IonicaBizauPage/posts/3015185775210024). That's why I do recommend talking to the right authorities before traveling because things are changing very fast. Faster than we can imagine.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## Advice by Country

### Australia

- https://covid19.homeaffairs.gov.au/

### Bulgaria

- IATA: https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm

### Canada

- https://www.canada.ca/en/public-health/services/diseases/2019-novel-coronavirus-infection/latest-travel-health-advice.html

### European Union information

- https://reopen.europa.eu/en

### France

- https://www.gouvernement.fr/en/coronavirus-covid-19

### Germany

- Federal Ministry of the Interior, Building and Community: https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/faqs/EN/topics/civil-protection/coronavirus/coronavirus-faqs.html#doc13797140bodyText3

### Iceland

- [www.covid.is](https://www.covid.is/categories/travel-to-and-within-iceland)

### India

- https://www.mohfw.gov.in/ (Tab Travel Advisories)
- https://boi.gov.in/
- Restricted international flights.
- Passenger trains and domestic flights are available with reduced schedule.

### Israel

- https://govextra.gov.il/ministry-of-health/corona/corona-virus-en/

### Italy

- http://www.salute.gov.it/portale/nuovocoronavirus/dettaglioFaqNuovoCoronavirus.jsp?lingua=italiano&id=228

### Japan

- https://www.mhlw.go.jp/stf/seisakunitsuite/bunya/newpage_00032.html

### Luxembourg

- https://msan.gouvernement.lu/en/dossiers/2020/corona-virus.html

### Nepal

- http://caanepal.gov.np/news/category/news

### Netherlands

- https://www.rivm.nl/en/news/current-information-about-novel-coronavirus-covid-19

### New Zealand

- https://www.immigration.govt.nz/about-us/covid-19/border-closures-and-exceptions

### Russia

- http://government.ru/en/news/39172/

### Singapore

- https://www.ica.gov.sg/covid-19
- [Only Citizens, PR and Limited work pass holders allowed entry. No transit for visitors.](https://www.moh.gov.sg/news-highlights/details/additional-border-control-measures-to-reduce-further-importation-of-covid-19-cases)
- [All travelers to fill arrival card before arriving in Singapore from March 27.](https://www.ica.gov.sg/news-and-publications/media-releases/media-release/all-travellers-arriving-in-singapore-from-27-march-2020-0900-hours-must-submit-health-declaration-via-the-sg-arrival-card-e-service)

### Sweden

- [Public health agency](https://www.folkhalsomyndigheten.se/the-public-health-agency-of-sweden/communicable-disease-control/covid-19/)
- [Krisinformation.se - Emergency information from Swedish authorities](https://www.krisinformation.se/en/hazards-and-risks/disasters-and-incidents/2020/official-information-on-the-new-coronavirus)

### Switzerland

- [Federal Office of Public Health](https://www.bag.admin.ch/bag/en/home/krankheiten/ausbrueche-epidemien-pandemien/aktuelle-ausbrueche-epidemien/novel-cov.html)
- [Entry restrictions](https://www.bag.admin.ch/bag/en/home/krankheiten/ausbrueche-epidemien-pandemien/aktuelle-ausbrueche-epidemien/novel-cov/massnahmen-des-bundes.html#-1151854284)

### UK

- https://www.gov.uk/guidance/travel-advice-novel-coronavirus

### USA

- https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/summary.html
- [What are the current travel restrictions on individuals entering the United States from regions affected by Covid-19?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/153131/what-are-the-current-travel-restrictions-on-individuals-entering-the-united-stat)

## General-Purpose Advice

### Air Travel Information

- IATA has the most up-to-date information on the topic: https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm
- Wikipedia:
- Travel Bans https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travel_restrictions_related_to_the_2019%E2%80%9320_coronavirus_pandemic
- Curfews https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curfews_and_lockdowns_related_to_the_2019%E2%80%9320_coronavirus_pandemic
- TIMATIC Search: http://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/countryinfo.html (general), http://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/spdbmainv.html (specific)

### Booking Sites Policies

- Booking.com: [Cancelling booking on Booking.com due to COVID-19](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/155128/22140)

Comment: any link for China travel policy?

Answer (score 1):

[covid19travel.com](https://covid19travel.com)

Updated daily, you can register for change alerts and contains all necessary links to government sites for each country.