# Where can I find current authoritative information about COVID-19 related travel bans to the US?

Tags: usa, covid-19

[BBC News reports](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-51804664):

> Under President Donald Trump, the federal government has banned non-citizens from coronavirus-hit regions entry, but US citizens are allowed back into the country after a two-week quarantine.

Does the US government publish a list of from where non-citizens are banned entry?

If yes, where can I find such a list?

I found a [coronavirus page at state.gov](https://www.state.gov/coronavirus/), but this appears aimed at advising US citizens where not to travel.  The entry ban is not (currently) mentioned on the [U.S. Embassy in Rome website](https://it.usembassy.gov/).  I don't find it at [CBP](https://www.cbp.gov/) or [DHS](https://www.dhs.gov/) pages either.  [This IATA list](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm) linked from [this related question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/154027/where-can-we-find-frequently-updated-details-about-travel-entry-restrictions-due) hasn't been updated since 2020-03-02 (nine days ago) and may not be accurate (at least it clearly contradicts the BBC News report).  The IATA list does not answer my question because it's not official information from the US government, and actually not even sourced to them.  It also appears to only relate to [Timatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timatic), and thus be limited to flights.

Comment: Looks like carelessly-worded reporting to me

Comment: Related: https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/after-travel-precautions.html

Comment: @JakeDot Informative — but the "stay home" advice implies it's aimed at US residents. It indirectly implies that Italy may be covered by a travel ban.

Comment: yes, but I haven't found any information on travel bans on CDC or some related departments' (like HHS) websites either.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link](https://www.politico.com/news/2020/03/11/text-of-suspension-of-travel-from-europe-126706) to the full text of the proclamation issued by Trump. The countries affected are those in the Schengen area, and this applies to anyone who has been in any Schengen country in the last 14 days, so even if your flights arrives from somewhere else, it would apply, for example.

> For purposes of this proclamation, the Schengen Area comprises 26
>   European states: Austria, Belgium, Czech Republic, Denmark, Estonia,
>   Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Hungary, Iceland, Italy, Latvia,
>   Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta, Netherlands, Norway,
>   Poland, Portugal, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain, Sweden, and Switzerland.

I will quote the meat of it below, which goes mostly over which persons are affected, and what the exceptions are:

> Section 1. Suspension and Limitation on Entry. The entry into the
>   United States, as immigrants or nonimmigrants, of all aliens who were
>   physically present within the Schengen Area during the 14-day period
>   preceding their entry or attempted entry into the United States is
>   hereby suspended and limited subject to section 2 of this
>   proclamation.
>
> Sec. 2. Scope of Suspension and Limitation on Entry.
>
> (a) Section 1 of this proclamation shall not apply to:
>
> (i) any lawful permanent resident of the United States;
>
> (ii) any alien who is the spouse of a U.S. citizen or lawful permanent
>   resident;
>
> (iii) any alien who is the parent or legal guardian of a U.S. citizen
>   or lawful permanent resident, provided that the U.S. citizen or lawful
>   permanent resident is unmarried and under the age of 21;
>
> (iv) any alien who is the sibling of a U.S. citizen or lawful
>   permanent resident, provided that both are unmarried and under the age
>   of 21;
>
> (v) any alien who is the child, foster child, or ward of a U.S.
>   citizen or lawful permanent resident, or who is a prospective adoptee
>   seeking to enter the United States pursuant to the IR-4 or IH-4 visa
>   classifications;
>
> (vi) any alien traveling at the invitation of the United States
>   Government for a purpose related to containment or mitigation of the
>   virus;
>
> (vii) any alien traveling as a nonimmigrant pursuant to a C-1, D, or
>   C-1/D nonimmigrant visa as a crewmember or any alien otherwise
>   traveling to the United States as air or sea crew;
>
> (viii) any alien
>
> (A) seeking entry into or transiting the United States pursuant to one
>   of the following visas: A-1, A-2, C-2, C-3 (as a foreign government
>   official or immediate family member of an official), E-1 (as an
>   employee of TECRO or TECO or the employee's immediate family members),
>   G-1, G-2, G-3, G-4, NATO-1 through NATO-4, or NATO-6 (or seeking to
>   enter as a nonimmigrant in one of those NATO categories); or
>
> (B) whose travel falls within the scope of section 11 of the United
>   Nations Headquarters Agreement;
>
> (ix) any alien whose entry would not pose a significant risk of
>   introducing, transmitting, or spreading the virus, as determined by
>   the Secretary of Health and Human Services, through the CDC Director
>   or his designee;
>
> (x) any alien whose entry would further important United States law
>   enforcement objectives, as determined by the Secretary of State, the
>   Secretary of Homeland Security, or their respective designees, based
>   on a recommendation of the Attorney General or his designee;
>
> (xi) any alien whose entry would be in the national interest, as
>   determined by the Secretary of State, the Secretary of Homeland
>   Security, or their designees; or
>
> (xii) members of the U.S. Armed Forces and spouses and children of
>   members of the U.S. Armed Forces.
>
> (b) Nothing in this proclamation shall be construed to affect any
>   individual's eligibility for asylum, withholding of removal, or
>   protection under the regulations issued pursuant to the legislation
>   implementing the Convention Against Torture and Other Cruel, Inhuman
>   or Degrading Treatment or Punishment, consistent with the laws and
>   regulations of the United States.
>
> Sec. 3. Implementation and Enforcement. (a) The Secretary of State
>   shall implement this proclamation as it applies to visas pursuant to
>   such procedures as the Secretary of State, in consultation with the
>   Secretary of Homeland Security, may establish. The Secretary of
>   Homeland Security shall implement this proclamation as it applies to
>   the entry of aliens pursuant to such procedures as the Secretary of
>   Homeland Security, in consultation with the Secretary of State, may
>   establish.
>
> (b) Consistent with applicable law, the Secretary of State, the
>   Secretary of Transportation, and the Secretary of Homeland Security
>   shall ensure that any alien subject to this proclamation does not
>   board an aircraft traveling to the United States.
>
> (c) The Secretary of Homeland Security may establish standards and
>   procedures to ensure the application of this proclamation at and
>   between all United States ports of entry.
>
> (d) An alien who circumvents the application of this proclamation
>   through fraud, willful misrepresentation of a material fact, or
>   illegal entry shall be a priority for removal by the Department of
>   Homeland Security.
>
> Sec. 4. Termination. This proclamation shall remain in effect until
>   terminated by the President. The Secretary of Health and Human
>   Services shall recommend that the President continue, modify, or
>   terminate this proclamation as described in section 5 of Proclamation
>   9984, as amended.
>
> Sec. 5. Effective Date. This proclamation is effective at 11:59 p.m.
>   eastern daylight time on March 13, 2020. This proclamation does not
>   apply to persons aboard a flight scheduled to arrive in the United
>   States that departed prior to 11:59 p.m. eastern daylight time on
>   March 13, 2020.
>
> Sec. 6. Severability. It is the policy of the United States to enforce
>   this proclamation to the maximum extent possible to advance the
>   national security, public safety, and foreign policy interests of the
>   United States. Accordingly:
>
> (a) if any provision of this proclamation, or the application of any
>   provision to any person or circumstance, is held to be invalid, the
>   remainder of this proclamation and the application of its provisions
>   to any other persons or circumstances shall not be affected thereby;
>   and
>
> (b) if any provision of this proclamation, or the application of any
>   provision to any person or circumstance, is held to be invalid because
>   of the lack of certain procedural requirements, the relevant executive
>   branch officials shall implement those procedural requirements to
>   conform with existing law and with any applicable court orders.
>
> Sec. 7. General Provisions. (a) Nothing in this proclamation shall be
>   construed to impair or otherwise affect:
>
> (i) the authority granted by law to an executive department or agency,
>   or the head thereof; or
>
> (ii) the functions of the Director of the Office of Management and
>   Budget relating to budgetary, administrative, or legislative
>   proposals.
>
> (b) This proclamation shall be implemented consistent with applicable
>   law and subject to the availability of appropriations.
>
> (c) This proclamation is not intended to, and does not, create any
>   right or benefit, substantive or procedural, enforceable at law or in
>   equity by any party against the United States, its departments,
>   agencies, or entities, its officers, employees, or agents, or any
>   other person.