# Are layovers included in the Schengen to USA COVID-19 travel ban?

Tags: usa, schengen, us-citizens, covid-19

Starting Friday the 13th, all non-USA passport holders are not allowed entry into the USA when coming from the Schengen area. Does this include layovers?

I'll be traveling from Africa, laying over in Frankfurt and finally arriving in Dulles. As a US citizen, what will be the impact of my layover?

Comment: The details are still scarce, the US administration has promised details to be forthcoming. The first impact is that your flight is likely to be cancelled. The second impact is that you'll have to go through additional interrogation on arrival, and could be required to go into quarantine.

Comment: It's not all non-USA passport holders.  Permanent residents and close family of US citizens are exempt, at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does this include layovers?

Yes, if you are an alien that does not fullfill one of the conditions of **section 2** and **were physically present within the Schengen Area during the 14-day period preceding their entry**, when the plane departed after **11:59 p.m. eastern daylight time on March 13, 2020**

> As a US citizen, what will be the impact of my layover?

Since a US-Citizen is not a alien, the proclamation does not apply.
Entry conditions for US-Citizens are not meationed in the proclamation.

---

> [Section 1.  Suspension and Limitation on Entry](https://www.whitehouse.gov/presidential-actions/proclamation-suspension-entry-immigrants-nonimmigrants-certain-additional-persons-pose-risk-transmitting-2019-novel-coronavirus/).  The entry into the United States, as immigrants or nonimmigrants, **of all aliens who were physically present within the Schengen Area during the 14-day period preceding their entry** or attempted entry into the United States is hereby suspended and limited subject to  section 2 of this proclamation.
>   ...

- [Answer containling compleate list contained in section 2](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/154921/95267)

> **Sec. 5.  Effective Date**.  This proclamation is effective at 11:59 p.m. eastern daylight time on March 13, 2020.  This proclamation **does not apply to persons aboard a flight scheduled to arrive in the United States that departed prior to 11:59 p.m. eastern daylight time on March 13, 2020**.

- 04:59 Central European Time,  Saturday, March 14, 2020

---

**Sources**:

- [Proclamation — Suspension of Entry as Immigrants and Nonimmigrants of Certain Additional Persons Who Pose a Risk of Transmitting 2019 Novel Coronavirus | The White House](https://www.whitehouse.gov/presidential-actions/proclamation-suspension-entry-immigrants-nonimmigrants-certain-additional-persons-pose-risk-transmitting-2019-novel-coronavirus/)

  - [Answer containling compleate list contained in  section 2](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/154921/95267)

Answer (score 2):

[CNN](https://edition.cnn.com/travel/article/coronavirus-us-travel-ban-stranded-travelers/index.html) states that:

> The ban, slated to begin on Friday, only applies to foreign nationals, not American citizens, their immediate family members and legal permanent residents.
>
> Returning travelers will be screened prior to entering the US and asked to self-quarantine for 14 days.

This is also confirmed by [The Telegraph](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2020/03/12/donald-trumps-travel-ban-affected-will-work/) and [Euronews](https://www.euronews.com/2020/03/12/coronavirus-trump-limits-all-travel-to-us-from-europe-except-uk).

It doesn't appear that any distinction is made between direct flights from Europe or layovers in Europe. The [proclamation](https://www.whitehouse.gov/presidential-actions/proclamation-suspension-entry-immigrants-nonimmigrants-certain-additional-persons-pose-risk-transmitting-2019-novel-coronavirus/) simply doesn't mention it.

All flights between the USA and mainland Europe [have been cancelled or interrupted](https://www.eturbonews.com/566827/all-flights-from-usa-and-europe-will-be-cancelled-as-of-friday-president-trump/) for the next 30 days [as of midnight on Friday, March 13th](https://qz.com/1816939/trump-suspends-europe-to-us-flights-to-fight-coronavirus/), and given that the majority of people in Europe or transiting in Europe won't be able to fly to the US (since they won't be permanent residents, citizens, etc.) I would recommend consulting your airline prior to flying to Europe since the onward leg may be cancelled.

Regarding cancellations, [Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/advisor/2020/03/11/master-list-of-airline-coronavirus-policies/#25feb2e46827) has stated:

> If your flight is cancelled by the airline, according to the US Department of Transportation you will be eligible for a cash refund, full stop. The European Union has a similar rule, commonly known as Rule 261, that provides for refunds for any flights that arrive into, travel through, or depart Europe.

You can read the full [proclamation](https://www.whitehouse.gov/presidential-actions/proclamation-suspension-entry-immigrants-nonimmigrants-certain-additional-persons-pose-risk-transmitting-2019-novel-coronavirus/) on the Whitehouse website.

Comment: To say that "All flights from the USA to mainland Europe have been canceled" isn't quite correct. The article you linked states that "All travel between the United States and Europe... will be canceled or interrupted for the next 30 days".

Comment: @lcode4food The article title deals only with USA->Europe, which states that all flights are cancelled. The part you have quoted deals with flights both ways. Perhaps there isn't actually a distinction, but that's how I read it. I'll edit my answer to be "between" so that there isn't any ambiguity.

Comment: If there are no flights in one directions, then the airlines will soon run out of planes going the other direction.

Comment: @gnasher That's mostly true, unless they consolidate flights to pick up US citizens, etc. instead of leaving them stranded on the wrong side of the pond. I wonder how the US govt. will handle stranded citizens.

Comment: @John the title of the article you linked to is patently false. Lufthansa and Air France among others have announced their intentions for flights from March 14th, and even though there is a reduction and lots of cancellations, there are still many flights.