# What restrictions apply to layovers in the Schengen area?

Tags: air-travel, schengen, layovers, covid-19

I want to fly from Croatia to the US. I am a US citizen, so I know that I will be able to get into the US. However, with COVID-19 restriction in place, am I able to take a flight with *layovers* in the Schengen area?

The exact flight that I am looking at includes going from Zagreb to Paris to New York.

I have already seen [Are layovers included in the Schengen to USA COVID-19 travel ban?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/154935/are-layovers-included-in-the-schengen-to-usa-covid-19-travel-ban), but that is asking about restrictions on traveling to the US, not about restrictions on travelling through the Schengen area.

Comment: Keep in mind that while you will be able to enter the US, your flight must be to a designated airport, and you will have to self-quarantine at home for 14 days.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Passengers in transit don't count as long as you're not going to another Schengen country, which you are not.

> **Entry restrictions**
>   A temporary travel restriction is in place until 15 April 2020 for travel from any country outside the EU to the following countries:
>
> - EU/Schengen: Austria, Belgium, Czech Republic, Denmark, Estonia, Finland, **France**, Germany, Greece, Hungary, Italy, Latvia, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta, Netherlands, Poland, Portugal, Romania, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain, Sweden
> - Associated countries: Iceland, Norway, Liechtenstein and Switzerland
>
> **Entry restriction exemptions:**
>
> - Citizens of all EU countries and the above associated countries (this includes citizens of the United Kingdom)
> - Family members of the EU and Associated State citizens
> - Long term residents, those with a legal right to reside or hold long term visas (D-visa) to any of the above countries
> - Any travelers having an essential function or need:
>
>   - **Passengers in transit (unless in transit to another EU or associated country where their entry would be banned)**
>   - Healthcare professions, healthcare researchers and elderly care professionals
>   - Frontier workers
>   - Transport personnel engaged in haulage of goods and other transport staff to the extent necessary
>   - Diplomats and staff of international organisations
>   - Military personnel
>   - Humanitarian aid workers in the exercise of their function
>   - Travelling for imperative family reasons (eg. attending a funeral)
>   - Those in need of international protection or for other humanitarian reasons

[Cathay Pacific](https://www.cathaypacific.com/cx/en_GB/travel-information/travel-preparation/travel-advisories/notice-regarding-travel-restrictions.html)