# Any updates on UK layovers restricted entry to US?

Tags: usa, uk, transit, covid-19, student-visas

I read [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/154935/114880) that someone having a layover in the given areas would also be restricted entry to the US. I'm an F1 student and am planning to fly from US to India for a month in December. The [CDC site](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/from-other-countries.html) was last updated on September 14, which is a month ago. I could not find an updated list of rules for nonimmigrants. As of now, I'm looking to book a flight that has a layover at LHR in London, which would put me in the list of restricted people on the way back. Is there a way I can confirm somewhere if that is the case and I should look for alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way I can confirm somewhere if that is the case

Yes. https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php (-> US) states F1 students can currently enter.

> Published 06.10.2020
>
> 1. Passengers who have transited or have been in Austria, Belgium, Brazil, China (People's Rep.), Czechia, Denmark, Estonia, Finland,
>    France, Germany, Greece, Hungary, Iceland, Iran, Ireland (Rep.),
>    Italy, Latvia, Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta,
>    Netherlands, Norway, Poland, Portugal, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain,
>    Sweden, Switzerland or in the United Kingdom (excluding overseas
>    territories outside of Europe), in the past 14 days are not allowed to
>    enter and transit.
>    -This does not apply to:
>
> - nationals and permanent residents of the USA;
> - spouses of nationals and of permanent residents of the USA. They must have a marriage certificate;
> - parents/legal guardians of an unmarried and younger than 21 years national or permanent resident of the USA;
> - the unmarried and younger than 21 years brother or sister of a national or permanent resident of the USA, who is unmarried and
>   younger than 21 years;
> - the child/foster child/ward of a national or permanent resident of the USA;
> - passengers with the following visas: A-1, A-2, C-1, C-1/D, C-2, C-3, CR-1, CR-2, D, E-1 (as an employee of TECRO or TECO or the employee's
>   immediate family members), G-1, G-2, G-3, G-4, IR-1, IR-4, IH-4,
>   NATO-1 through NATO-4, or NATO-6 visa;
> - members of the U.S. Armed Forces, spouses, and children of members of the U.S. Armed Forces;
> - passengers with evidence of traveling at the invitation of the USA government for a purpose related to the containment/mitigation of the
>   Coronavirus (COVID-19);
> - passengers with documents issued by the U.S. Department of Homeland Security, U.S. Customs and Border Protection, or U.S. Department of
>   State indicating that the passenger is exempt from the restriction;
> - B1 crew crewmembers that are engaged in lightering, Outer Continental Shelf (OCS) activity, wind farm activity, private air/sea
>   crew and other similar crewmember activities;
> - **students with an F-1 or M-1 visa and their F-2 and M-2 dependents, if they arrive from or have been in Ireland (Rep.), United Kingdom or
>   Schengen Member States in the past 14 days.**

Comment: This is correct as of now, though the question asks us to be sure of what will happen in December, which is of course impossible (there is also no special reason to think things will change dramatically, but US immigration and covid policies are quite volatile).

Comment: @mlc agreed on both points.

Comment: @mlc I didn't mean to ask of things in December. Since the original proclamations I read said nothing about F1 visa, I just wanted to make sure that such a transit wouldn't put me in the restricted list, as the rules stand now. If they do in the future, that would be another matter.