# Is there an authoritative source for COVID-19 related travel restrictions in the EU?

Tags: borders, eu, covid-19

Similar to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/154877/13208) but for the EU. I need to repatriate myself and my car from Prague to London. Ideally I would cross the Czech/German, German/Dutch, Dutch/Belgian, Belgian/French, and French/British borders but the list of countries could be varied by increasing the length of my journey.

I am finding it very hard to tell if I will be denied entry at any of the borders I need to cross. All I can find are vague media reports which use phrases such as *"limited to essential travel"*. It's not clear what constitutes essential travel, and specifically whether returning to my home country will be sufficient reason for a country to allow me in. For example, they may reason that I can return home by finding a route that bypasses them, and therefore it is not "essential" that I cross their border.

I hold a British passport, Czech residency permit, and have homes in both countries. The UK is my primary residence.

I have a ferry booked from France -> UK and as far as I can tell entries are still permitted there.

Are there any authoritative sources of information where I can find out exactly what the restrictions are within the EU? Alternatively, individual sources for the countries I'm travelling through would be helpful.

Comment: You say you’re returning to your home country, but it’s not clear where you are resident?

Comment: @Traveller Sorry, I thought that was clear from "I need to repatriate myself and my car from Prague to London". I have edited the question to provide more details in case it is useful.

Comment: We have this overall question, not sure how helpful it is: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/154027/where-can-we-find-frequently-updated-details-about-travel-entry-restrictions-due

Answer (score 2):

Here is a part answer for the Germany leg of your trip

[Coronavirus: Fragen und Antworten](https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/faqs/DE/themen/bevoelkerungsschutz/coronavirus/coronavirus-faqs.html) see the question "Bei welchen dringenden Gründen ist ein Grenzübertritt gestattet?" (What are the urgent reasons for crossing a border?)

> Zudem bleibt die Rückreise von EU-Bürgern und Drittstaatsangehörigen in ihre Herkunftsstaaten oder in den Staat, in dem sie zum Aufenthalt (längerfristige Aufenthaltstitel) berechtigt sind, mittels Transit durch Deutschland zulässig.

And here the [google translate](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=en&text=Zudem%20bleibt%20die%20R%C3%BCckreise%20von%20EU-B%C3%BCrgern%20und%20Drittstaatsangeh%C3%B6rigen%20in%20ihre%20Herkunftsstaaten%20oder%20in%20den%20Staat%2C%20in%20dem%20sie%20zum%20Aufenthalt%20(l%C3%A4ngerfristige%20Aufenthaltstitel)%20berechtigt%20sind%2C%20mittels%20Transit%20durch%20Deutschland%20zul%C3%A4ssig.)

> In addition, EU citizens and third-country nationals can return to their home countries or to the country in which they are entitled to stay (long-term residence permits) by transit through Germany.