# Iceland Covid restrictions for tourists

Tags: international-travel, covid-19, iceland

Does anyone have information /can point out reliable source on Iceland Covid restrictions for tourist travelling to Iceland in July 2020 ?

Comment: The Covid crisis has been fast moving and the situation everywhere has been subject to change at short notice. You could take a look at [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/154036/105640) for what advice currently exists.

Answer (score 1):

(a simple internet search would have helped you)

https://www.government.is/news/article/2020/05/12/Testing-for-international-arrivals-could-start-in-June/

...No later than 15 June 2020, **travelers are expected to be given a choice between a two-week quarantine or being tested for the virus upon arrival, or otherwise proving that they are free of coronavirus infection**. Exact requirements are still being developed **but travelers will likely be required to download and use the official tracing app already in use by 40% of the population in Iceland**. The app has been developed following the strictest privacy standards, with location data stored locally on the user's device unless released for tracing purposes in case of an infection....

(my take) If everything goes according to plan, i.e. no new increase in infections due to foreign travelers, I assume the same directives will be kept for a while.

So in July, you will probably need to follow the same guidelines.