# Can I book a roundtrip flight with a visa that expires before the return flight? (I understand that I will have to extend the visa while there.)

Tags: visas, denial-of-entry, visa-expiration, return-tickets

Can I book a roundtrip flight with a visa that expires before the return flight? (I understand that I will have to extend the visa while there.) The visa has too much time on it to review, plus the US Embassy here is not really taking new applications right now due to COVID-19. I would like to return a month after my current visa expires. Will I be allowed entry and allowed to fly?

Comment: A visa for what country?  For the US, your visa is only required to be valid on the date you enter, and there is no need to extend it.

Comment: Yes it is for the US. Ok, so sounds like I'm ok to book?

Comment: What is your citizenship? Where are you flying from and when?

Comment: You are aware that non-US citizens who have been in a large number of countries (including all Schengen countries, the UK and Ireland) are no longer allowed in the US even with a visa, right? And that there are very very few international flights to the US?

Comment: In general, airlines do not verify immigration details when booking, so you can book the flight with no visa. However, at check-in the immigration details should be checked.

Comment: For ‘will I be allowed entry’ refer to https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/153131/what-are-the-current-travel-restrictions-on-individuals-entering-the-united-stat

Answer (score 1):

**You can book a flight without having any kind of visa.**

Airlines do not check that you have a valid visa when you book a flight, because lots of people choose to buy a flight before they get the visa.

They will check your visa when you board, and if you don't have a visa by then you will be denied boarding and not given a refund.

Whether you are going to get a US visa, or be permitted to enter the US with or without a visa will depend hugely on the state of Covid-19 at the time.