# I need to fly from Germany to US ASAP. I’m holding EU passport

Tags: covid-19, travel-ban

My partner live in the states and I live in Europe. We not married so no legal union. However I still wanna go to him in the States ASAP. The Schengen travel van should expire today but no news of renewal and I can’t get in touch with any embassy. Do you have any idea of what’s gonna happen and if I can travel?

Thank you!

Comment: Essential trips only. No legal union = no sufficient reason to travel.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the current travel restrictions on individuals entering the United States from regions affected by Novel Coronavirus?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/153131/what-are-the-current-travel-restrictions-on-individuals-entering-the-united-stat)

Comment: Not really. I understand these conditions. But the ban was for 30 days only and no official news of renewal at this stage. So I wonder if will be extended or not.

Comment: Please sign in to the same account you used to ask your question, that way we can be sure that later posts are by the same person, and you can post edits and comments that way.

Comment: Just read that Germany is preparing a relaxation in regards to travel for emergency reasons. They said end of April. Check with local authorities.

Comment: I would expect , that unless stated otherwise the ban is still applicable; whether or not there is a date limit.

Comment: “Need to” and “want to” are very different things. I don’t think you actually need to, do you?

Answer (score 11):

Your statements are incorrect. The US travel ban on people who have been in the Schengen Area does not expire today at all.

[Proclamation 9993](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2020/03/16/2020-05578/suspension-of-entry-as-immigrants-and-nonimmigrants-of-certain-additional-persons-who-pose-a-risk-of) states:

> **Sec. 4**. *Termination*. This proclamation shall remain in effect until terminated by the President. The Secretary of Health and Human Services shall recommend that the President continue, modify, or terminate this proclamation as described in section 5 of Proclamation 9984, as amended.

So there was never a 30-day limit. It remains in place as long as needed, and it seems unlikely this will change anytime soon.

Note however that the ban is on non-US citizens who have been in the listed countries in the last 14 days, not citizens or permanent residents of those countries. So you could try to travel to another country and wait for 14 days and then travel to the US.

There are however a lot of things that would hamper such an attempt:

- many countries ban entry likewise (or even altogether).
- There are similar US bans for many other countries, and they may add more
- Most European countries ban any unnecessary travel
- Plane travel is probably one of the worst possible things you could do to try to avoid catching the virus and/or spreading it around.

So I very very strongly recommend you stay where you are and wait for things to calm down.