# Who can enter USA now?

Tags: visas, usa, air-travel, paperwork, covid-19

I am not from the banned area with B visa. However, when I buy ticket my staff of airline told me that only have B visa cannot enter USA now, even if I am not from banned area, is it correct? Do anyone enter USA recently?

Update: I am from Hong Kong and hold a Hong Kong passport, I am back to HK since this April and have no travel since then.

My flight will transit in ICN airport, Korea.

Comment: Unfortunately there are several different "banned areas".  Can you tell us your citizenship, as well as which countries you have visited in the past 14 days?

Comment: @NateEldredge And which countries (via transit) you'll visit on the way...a transit visa may require passing Immigration and "entering" the transit country.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Even direct airside transit disqualifies you, and the CBP will know through APIS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the current travel restrictions on individuals entering the United States from regions affected by Novel Coronavirus?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/153131/what-are-the-current-travel-restrictions-on-individuals-entering-the-united-stat)

Comment: @NateEldredge as far as I know all the travel restrictions apply to all foreigners based on their physical presence in certain places.  Citizenship is not relevant beyond knowing that the traveler is not a US national, which we know because a US national cannot hold a B visa.

Comment: @phoog: Well, the advice from the airline could be based on something other than a Covid-19 travel ban (e.g. EO 13780).  If OP will state their citizenship then we could try to figure out if there's some other reason why they might not be allowed to travel, or else reassure them that they are.

Comment: FYI [Flying from Bangkok to the United States via South Korea (Incheon): will the passenger be quarantined in South Korea?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/157970/1810)

Answer (score 5):

Airlines go by the TIMATIC database, which states:

> --Passengers who have transited or have been in Austria, Belgium, Brazil, China (People's Rep.), Czechia, Denmark, Estonia, Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Hungary, Iceland, Iran, Ireland (Rep.), Italy, Latvia, Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta, Netherlands, Norway, Poland, Portugal, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland or in the United Kingdom (excluding overseas territories outside of Europe), in the past 14 days are not allowed to enter the USA.

(followed by exceptions)

So if you've stayed outside these countries in the past 14 days, you're allowed to enter the USA.