# Can French citizens flying from Bangkok BKK to SFO do an international, cross-terminal transit in Manila Airport (MNL) with the COVID-19 restrictions?

Tags: transit, transit-visas, covid-19, french-citizens, mnl

[Ninoy Aquino International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ninoy_Aquino_International_Airport) (NAIA) a.k.a. Manila Airport (MNL) has [4 passenger terminals](https://www.manila-airport.net/) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200816214152/https://www.manila-airport.net/)), 3 of them serving international flights:

> - NAIA Terminal 1: NAIA Terminal 1 serves almost all the international flights. It has west gates 1-7 and east gates 9-15.
> - NAIA Terminal 2: NAIA Terminal 2 houses international and domestic flights of the country’s flag carrier, Philippine Airlines or PAL.
> - NAIA Terminal 3: NAIA Terminal 3 serves the international flights which are not handled in NAIA - Terminal 1 as well as some domestic
>   flights.
> - NAIA Terminal 4: NAIA Terminal 4 hosts flights from local and regional carriers.

I read on http://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/countryinfo.html (Philippines -> Visa -> TWOV) (thanks [Crazydre](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/39782/crazydre) for [pointing me to it](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/158740/can-french-citizens-flying-from-bangkok-bkk-do-an-international-transit-in-han#comment397416_158742)):

> Philippines (PH): TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>
> - Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.
> - **TWOV does not apply when transiting between terminals**. A visa and an airline escort are required.
> - TWOV does not apply to refugees and stateless persons.

This "TWOV does not apply when transiting between terminals" causes me concern, as I am considering taking the flight BKK ---(PR 731)---> MNL ---(PR 104)---> SFO, and PR 731 lands at MNL on Terminal 2 whereas PR 104 departs from MNL on Terminal 1.

Can French citizens flying from Bangkok (BKK) to San Francisco airport (SFO) do an international, cross-terminal transit in Manila Airport (MNL) with the ongoing COVID-19 travel restriction? Will I need a transit visa, and if so, can I get one on arrival or prior to departure?

Assume:

- the French citizen has no tie and no visa/paperwork with Philippines;
- "international transit" in Manila Airport (MNL) means that the route is: outside Philippines -> MNL -> outside Philippines;
- "cross-terminal transit" means transit between two different terminals do the same airport.

---

Details regarding the flight information:

[Flight PR 731](https://www.google.com/search?q=PR+731) ([mirror](http://archive.is/EYCdp)):

[image]

[Flight PR 104](https://www.google.com/search?q=PR+104) ([mirror](https://archive.vn/CTib1)):

[image]

[Flight BKK -> PR 731 -> MNL -> PR 104 -> SFO](https://flights.app.goo.gl/7E5SH) ([mirror](https://archive.vn/nx55Y)):

[image]

---

The [IATA information about Philippines](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php) says nothing about transit and transit visas aside from "Suspension of all visa exemptions and visa on arrival facilities", which leaves the door open for obtaining a transit visa prior to departure if that's possible:

> Philippines (Published 06.08.2020)
>
> 1. Passengers are not allowed to enter. This does not apply to:
>
> - nationals of the Philippines;
> - spouses or children of nationals of the Philippines traveling together or traveling to join the national of Philippines;
> - merchant seamen with a 9(c) visa issued by the Philippines;
> - nationals of India with a Temporary Resident Visa;
> - nationals of China (People's Rep.) with a Permanent Resident Visa who is spouse of a national of the Philippines;
> - passengers with a 13(a), 13(b), 13(c), 13(d), 13(e), 13(g), RA 7919, EO324 or Native-born visa issued by the Philippines.
>
> 2. **Suspension of all visa exemptions and visa on arrival facilities**.
>
> - This does not apply to spouses or children of a national of the Philippines.
> - This does not apply to parents of a minor who is a national of the Philippines.
>
> 3. Passengers are subject to a Coronavirus (COVID-19) test at their own expense, they are subject to quarantine and must present a
>    completed Case Investigation Form.
> 4. Passengers traveling to Davao (DVO) must have a medical certificate with a negative Coronavirus (COVID-19) test result issued at most 72
>    hours before departure.

Comment: Is this what you did past week?

Comment: @BernhardDöbler no

Comment: Close voter: this question has nothing to do with WANTA.

Comment: @Franck Dernoncourt You made it out of the US, I assume https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/158793/am-i-allowed-to-go-to-the-airport-to-catch-a-flight-if-i-am-supposed-to-self-qua

Comment: @Traveller planning ahead

Comment: I strongly suggest calling Philippine Airlines. It's their booking an d home base, so they should know the rules and current processes for transiting. Covid is highly volatile situation, rules change quickly and websites are updated slowly and are often out of date. Case in point: we are going on an international tomorrow and the ONLY complete set of information of what happens when we got by talking to the airline on the phone. Even their own website was spotty and incomplete.

Comment: @Hilmar thanks, I view it as the last resort, as I've been told incorrect information several times in the time by airline's customer services, and whatever they tell me isn't legally binding. I'll probably opt to transit somewhere else if I can't find the information without going through the customer service. Eg NRT transit is ok from my understanding.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I'd interpret the TIMATIC info as inter-terminal transit **not** being allowed for you. To be sure, email the immigration head office - send one message to xinfo@immigration.gov.ph **and** immigph@gmail.com **and** binoc_immigration@hotmail.ph.

Comment: @Crazydre Thanks, I'll email them now (I emailed  Philippine Airlines at ticket@palbkk.com and pao@miaagovphils.onmicrosoft.com and two hours ago). I'll keep you posted if I hear back from them.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Airlines will usually pull the good old "call the embassy" card. If I knew the handling agent for PAL at BKK, I'd strongly advise you to email them, as they decide whether you get onboard. As I don't know the company, definitely try to get a reply from the PAL office at BKK (as well)

Comment: @Crazydre Thanks, agreed, ticket@palbkk.com is PAL at BKK.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt In absence of a clear reply from either PAL at BKK or Philippine immigration, I wouldn't have risked this (and I've gone so far as to successfully challenge European handling agents making incorrect assessments in advance). NRT is a safe bet though - it'd take a hardcore amateur of a check-in supervisor for you to be denied boarding for that.

Comment: @Crazydre Thanks, NRT is indeed the backup is MNL isn't cleared. Backup #2 is ICN, though I'm [not 100% sure about it](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/157970/1810). But I'd rather not fly via Europe.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Wrote an answer about ICN - that's OK too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Philippine Airlines Ticket Town Office in Bangkok claims that "Philippine are still banned for all passenger transit flights to other countries":

> ---------- Forwarded message ---------
> From: Ticket Town Office Philippine Airlines ticket@palbkk.com 
> Date: Wed, 19 Aug 2020 at
> 19:07 
> Subject: Re: Can French citizens flying from Bangkok BKK to SFO
> do an international, cross-terminal transit in Manila Airport (MNL)
> with the COVID-19 restrictions? 
> To: Franck Dernoncourt
>
> Dear Sir,
>  Please be inform you that. As of now Philippine are still
> banned for all passenger transit flights to other countries.
> For more
> information. Please see the below link.
> [https://www.philippineairlines.com/en/ph/home/covid-19/arrivingintheph](https://www.philippineairlines.com/en/ph/home/covid-19/arrivingintheph%C2%A0)
>
> Best regards, 
> Saowanee
>
> > On Thu, Aug 20, 2020 at 1:15 AM Franck Dernoncourt
> > wrote: 
> > Hi, 
> > I am
> > considering taking the flight BKK -> PR 731 -> MNL -> PR 104 -> SFO
> > soon. However, PR 731 lands at MNL on Terminal 2 whereas PR 104
> > departs from MNL on Terminal
> > 1.
> >
> > I read on http://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/countryinfo.html
> > (Philippines -> Visa -> TWOV): "TWOV does not apply when transiting
> > between terminals. A visa and an airline escort are required.", which
> > causes me concern since to go from PR 731 to PR 104 I would have to
> > transit from terminal 1 to terminal 2. 
> > Can French citizens
> > flying from Bangkok (BKK) to San Francisco airport (SFO) do an
> > international, cross-terminal transit in Manila Airport (MNL) with the
> > ongoing COVID-19 travel restriction? Will I need a transit visa, and
> > if so, can I get one on arrival or prior to departure?
> >
> > Thanks, 
> > Franck

I emailed the immigration head office at xinfo@immigration.gov.ph and immigph@gmail.com and binoc_immigration@hotmail.ph, as [Crazydre](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/39782/crazydre) [suggested](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/158885/can-french-citizens-flying-from-bangkok-bkk-to-sfo-do-an-international-cross-te/158944#comment398186_158885) but they never replied to my inquiry. (Update 2020-12-24: I never got a reply from them).

Comment: Why the downvote? Just shooting the messenger here. Email ticket@palbkk.com if you disagree with them.

Comment: Seems legit enough