# I am stuck in transit in Malaysia from Australia

Tags: visas, transit, australian-citizens, malaysia, philippines

I was travelling from Australia to the Philippines with a stopover in Malaysia, to meet my wife and daughter. They almost refused to let me board the plane in Melbourne because I didn’t have a face shield, which was a requirement by the Philippines. Someone at the airport gave me a face shield and everything was solved and I boarded the plane. But when I came to Malaysia, I wasn’t allowed to board the plane to the Philippines because they told me that I had to have a visa to enter the Philippines due to a law that commenced on 7 December.

I bought my ticket on the 27th of November and checked the Philippines embassy website in Australia and saw not a word about the new law. It all said visa-free entry into the Philippines. If the Malaysian airlines refused my entry on the plane in Australia because of a face shield how come they didn’t refuse me or even check my visa for the Philippines? Because of this now I am stuck in Malaysia and can’t go to the Philippines or back to Australia. Even if I go back to Australia, I was told that I have to quarantine for 14 days in a hotel which is going to cost me over $3000. I am stressed and currently living in the airport in Kuala Lumpur and paying for all the expenses, hotel, food, and I was told that I even had to pay for my return flight to Australia.

What can I do about this?

---

I am an Australian citizen and my spouse and my child are Filipino citizens. I know Australian citizens could travel visa-free because I travelled to the Philippines 7 or 8 times before visa free. But on the 7th of December, the new law came into effect in Philippines where no one is visa free. The only way anyone can travel visa free is only if you enter the Philippines with your wife or child who is a Filipino. There is no more visa-free entry and this is not updated on their website on any Philippines embassy websites.

**Added from a comment posted to an answer on 23th or 24th December:**
I can go back now. I just found out today that they have requested to accept an extra person into Australia from Malaysia because they only allow limited number of people to enter the country. This has happened because I told Malaysian Airlines that I will go to media about this when I return to Australia and I received so much assistance today which I never received since Saturday. They didn’t give me my luggage before but today I got to get some clothes out of my luggage. I have been wearing the same clothes since Saturday hahaha

Comment: Are you an Australian citizen?  If so, you may be able to apply for [loa  ns to help cover your living expenses & return flight.](https://www.smartraveller.gov.au/COVID-19/COVID-19-overseas-financial-assistance)  It may be a long shot, but it's worth looking into.

Comment: Were both legs of the journey one booking (same PNR) with Malaysia Airlines? What was your travel date? Did you check entry requirements again in between booking on 27 Nov and travelling?

Comment: What are your citizenship and your place of residence, and those of your spouse and child? If you are not a Filipino national but your wife is, you are visa-exempt only if you travel with her (and are a national of one of the countries on the visa-free list). If you are not travelling with her, a visa is required. You also need to have bookings for a quarantine facility and for testing.

Comment: With face shield I assume you mean a mouth-nose mask?

Comment: Yes. I checked on the Philippines embassy in Australia website on the 12th of December and I checked again on the 19th of December both on the Philippines embassy website in Australia and Malaysia. They both said the same things, I can travel to Manila visa free for 30 days. I took scene shots of this showing the website also

Comment: I had the mask already. Face shield is the plastic shield that covers your eyes.

Comment: I am an Australian citizen and my spouse and my child is a Filipino citizen. Australian citizens can travel visa free because I travelled to Philippines 7 or 8 times before visa free. But on the 7th of December the new law came into effect in Philippines where no one is visa free. The only way anyone can travel visa free is only if you enter the Philippines with your wife or child who is a Filipino. There is no more visa free and this is not updated on their website on any Philippines embassy websites

Comment: There’s actually a link to that info on the site of the embassy of the Philippines in Australia (link to images posted on Facebook...). No idea when they added that, though. They say the changes date back to November 27th. They were posted on Facebook on Dec 3rd.

Comment: I'm not sure what or where you checked... The Internet Archive's capture of https://philembassy.org.au on [November 24th](https://web.archive.org/web/20201124211121/https://philembassy.org.au/) clearly shows that at the time (effective Nov 1st), foreign spouses of Filipinos were allowed only with a valid visa (even those who entered without a visa previously) **and** pre-booked accredited quarantine facility and pre-booked COVID-19 testing and subject to maximum capacity limits.

Comment: I have just checked again. Here is the link about visa for Australians required to travel Philippines. https://www.philembassy.org.au/consular/visa

Comment: The same was true on the capture from [November 13th](https://web.archive.org/web/20201113170925/https://philembassy.org.au/). And in your case, the same requirements already existed before that (at least going back to September).

Comment: I know that this rule came into effect on 7 December, not before because I was shown the documents and publications at the Kuala Lumpur airport

Comment: @Tamer those are the generic rules not taking into account the Covid situation. There are lots of additional requirements that were introduced over the year.

Comment: Check this link about visa on the Philippines embassy website in Australia https://dms.philembassy.org.au/index.php/website/consular/visa/87-foreign-nationals-

Comment: @Tamer the latest rules came into effect 7 December (I believe they are actually a relaxation of the rules for foreign spouses travelling with the Filipino national, who now no longer require a visa, though I haven't really gone into the details). But the requirement for a visa existed way before that.

Comment: Can your wife come to Malaysia and then you go to Philippines together?

Comment: Not surprised given the lack of clear info from filipino immigration https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/158885/1810

Answer (score 18):

The traveller owns the responsibility for ensuring they have all relevant valid travel documents or ability to transit or enter into countries, either their destination or any transit stop along the way.

Airlines have no liability to the passenger for ensuring their documents are valid, or whether they actually have the ability to enter the destination country - what they do have is a liability to the destination or transit country to not present ineligible persons, and they typically get fined when that happens, but that liability infers no responsibility to the actual passenger.

You have two options - firstly, check what your travel insurance can do in this situation.  They may be able to pay out for some expenses for example

Secondly, you will want to contact your country's embassy or consulate in Malaysia - they may be able to repatriate you or otherwise help you out.

You may also want to seek help from friends and family, or try opening a GoFundMe and publicise your situation.

Comment: Ok. Why did they refuse me entry in Australia on the plane because I didn’t have a face shield. It is not a requirement for Malaysia, only requirement for Philippines

Comment: This is the question that no one can answer me in Malaysia including the managers of Malaysian Airlines

Comment: @Tamer you will have to ask them that, but its also a good practice to ensure the health and well being of fellow passengers and the crew in this current pandemic.  But it doesnt infer any responsibility to you on the airline at all for your eligibility to enter the destination.  Thats all you.

Comment: @Tamer there are so many rules and regulations (and exceptions) and they change to often that it is difficult for them to know and check them all, especially when you are not flying direct to the destination country (they have to check passengers against different rules for each of their final destinations). In theory they should have checked your paperwork at the origin airport, but they are not liable to anything if they don’t. The passenger bears sole responsibility, I’m afraid.

Comment: I did ask them that and the only answer I get is I shouldn’t have been allowed on the plane in Australia. They laughed at me when I said I was refused entry because I didn’t have a face shield but they didn’t refuse me to board the plane because I didn’t have a visa. I have this on voice recorder where they admitted their mistake

Comment: @Tamer Having a recording of  them "admitting their mistake" will not make any difference. The airline has no duty to you to check whether you have the right visa. They say so in the terms and conditions of your ticket

Comment: So what you’re saying is you could buy a ticket to any place in the world and jump on a plane and go there. Because they will not check your visa to board the plane. Maybe you will get knocked back when you land but at least you can travel on the plane. Am I right?

Comment: @Tamer Airlines will typically check paperwork required for entry. But **you** are ultimately responsible for ensuring you have the correct documentation, not the airline. There are plenty of examples of this on TSE, search ‘denial of entry’ tag. Why can’t you go back to Australia?

Comment: @Tamer The only reason airlines check is that in many cases the destination country can fine them if they let someone board a plane without evidence they will be allowed into the country, and will also have to transport the passenger back. But airlines have no obligation **to you** to check your documents, quite the opposite: your contract with them most likely states that they can bill you for all costs incurred in such a situation, including fines, penalties, fees, the cost of the flight,

Comment: @Traveller There is a requirement for a quarantine (a real one, not the self-isolation joke we see in other countries) that has to be paid for by the traveller, **and** there are quotas on the number of Australians allowed back. Some Australias have been stuck out of Australia for months waiting for a flight back (airlines of course prefer to fly only premium classes and more expensive fares...).

Comment: I can go back now. I just found out today that they have requested to accept an extra person into Australia from Malaysia because they only allow limited number of people to enter the country. This has happened because I told Malaysian Airlines that I will go to media about this when I return to Australia and I received so much assistance today which I never received since Saturday. They didn’t give me my luggage before but today I got to get some clothes out of my luggage. I have been wearing the same clothes since Saturday hahaha

Answer (score 4):

Although being stuck isn't your fault, it seems that no entity (airline or government) has the responsibility to solve your problem, so you'll have to do it yourself.

Apart from going back to Australia, one alternative option is to travel to a 3rd country which allows Australians to enter (perhaps UAE) and apply for a Philippines visa there (if you qualify, check beforehand). This involves additional flight and hotel costs, but might work out better than going back to Australia and paying for quarantine there.