# Can Indian citizen with B1/B2 visa travel in foreign flights during COVID?

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens, b1-b2-visas, covid-19

Indian govt declare some air bubble to travel, where they will allow foreign airlines to operate in Indian airport.

My parents have valid B1/B2 visa, can they travel in any foreign airlines?

As per my knowledge, the Vande Bharat special flight which was the only option to travel during lockdown in India, were allowing only GC, Citizen or valid work permit visa holder to travel from  India to USA.

Is there any restriction for tourist visa holder in USA in corona time?

Some news reference

https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/business/india-business/bubble-brings-relief-diplomats-oci-card-indian-passport-holders-can-travel-on-uniteds-us-india-flights/articleshow/77021841.cms

https://www.news18.com/news/auto/flying-to-germany-france-us-becomes-easy-as-govt-finalizes-air-bubble-for-international-flights-2718939.html

https://www.tribuneindia.com/news/nation/limited-flights-air-bubble-with-france-us-113900

Answer (score 2):

Indian government doesn't place much restriction in traveling outside country. Most restrictions are placed by receiving countries. If you qualify for admission in receiving country, you can travel on Vande Bharat flights.

From [this post](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/153131/what-are-the-current-travel-restrictions-on-individuals-entering-the-united-stat), you need to qualify any of the following criteria in order to get admitted to USA. Without these, you won't be allowed to board the flight.

> ```
> US citizens and nationals
> lawful permanent residents (green card holders)
> spouses of citizens or LPRs
> parents of unmarried citizens/LPRs under 21
> siblings of citizens/LPRs, both unmarried and under 21
> children, foster children, and adoptees of citizens/LPRs
> air and sea crew members
> diplomats and foreign officials
> those granted exceptions by high-level officials
> ```

Just a valid B1/B2 visa doesn't qualify.

Comment: I'm not sure that these restrictions are up-to-date.  I have heard that B1/B2 visas are now valid for _air_ travel into the US (land borders are still closed to tourism).  I will see if I can find a source

Comment: Not an official source, but see https://www.traveloffpath.com/u-s-reopening-for-tourism-everything-you-need-to-know/ for example

Comment: I am also looking for some valid source, like there is no special mentioned on b1/b2 not allowed or allowed

Comment: Thanks Anish, I know Vande Bharat will not allow B1/B2, but Indian govt allowed foreign airlines. Does they allow B1/B2 or they also take only GC or Citizen ?

Comment: "From this post, you need to qualify any of the following criteria in order to get admitted to USA." Only if you have been physically present in Mainland China, Iran, the Schengen Area, the UK, Ireland, or Brazil in the previous 14 days. Otherwise, that doesn't apply.

Comment: yes, but I didn't get any official source, I called airlines, and they informed, that I have to check with USA govt. They will sell the ticket, but they can't refund if you cant board to flight due to your visa :(