# Enter US from Hong Kong during covid possible?

Tags: covid-19, seattle

I am wondering whether I as HK resident (German citizen) can currently enter the United States by flying from Hong Kong (via transit in Vancouver) to Seattle Tacoma airport?

In the following link it states that those from China cannot enter the US but that Hong Kong is excluded. Can anyone who may have further information shed some light into whether I can currently enter the US through Seattle international airport?

https://www.whitehouse.gov/presidential-actions/proclamation-suspension-entry-immigrants-nonimmigrants-persons-pose-risk-transmitting-2019-novel-coronavirus/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the current travel restrictions on individuals entering the United States from regions affected by Covid-19?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/153131/what-are-the-current-travel-restrictions-on-individuals-entering-the-united-stat)

Comment: Excellent, not an authoritative source but a good guide. HK residents seem to be excluded from the travel ban. Thanks

Comment: It's worth noting that the US recently (2020-07-14) moved to treat HK as equivalent to mainland China for the purposes of several economic & immigration laws, in response to the new Chinese laws applying to HK.  This uniform treatment does not appear to have been extended to travel restrictions, though (at least not yet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can currently enter the US by air if you have not been physically present in Mainland China, Iran, the Schengen Area, the UK, Ireland, or Brazil in the last 14 days, and presence in Hong Kong or Macau do not count as presence in Mainland China. Your citizenship and residence are irrelevant. You did not say in your question what regions you have been to recently, so we cannot determine the answer for certain.