# Does visiting your child count as an exception to the US entry rules?

Tags: usa, covid-19, dutch-citizens, quarantine

As a Dutch citizen I would not normally be allowed to fly to the US at the moment from the Netherlands. However my 13 year old daughter lives there with her mother. Does this count as an exception that would give me permission to fly?

Comment: Is your daughter a US citizen?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes. Does that help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the current travel restrictions on individuals entering the United States from regions affected by Covid-19?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/153131/what-are-the-current-travel-restrictions-on-individuals-entering-the-united-stat)

Comment: You can fly to the US without any restrictions by staying in a different country for 14 days first. Turkey is currently a popular option.

Comment: @JonathanReez Please do not suggest unethical methods to circumvent travel bans. I expected better from a diamond.

Comment: @Nzall What is unethical about it?

Comment: @Szabolcs It's pretending like you're from a different country than you actually are from in order to mislead immigration staff. It's essentially lying to immigration workers for your own benefit, and if you would do it on something else like your VISA application or your passport, you'd be banned for years for doing it.

Comment: @Nzall I think you missed the point: there’s no suggestion to circumvent anything. The ban applies to people who have been in the designated countries in the last 14 days. If you stay out of those countries for 14 days, you’re no longer in the scope of the ban. What would be unethical would be to travel through that other country and pretend you’ve been there for 14 days when you haven’t, but that is not what was suggested.

Comment: The only problem may be that the numbers of cases change, so some countries can be moved from the 'acceptable' list to the 'unacceptable' list, while you are in that country.

Comment: @Willeke Yes. Does the US normally give a few days warning when it does that?

Comment: @JonathanReez Having to stay in a different country before going to the US sounds like a restriction to me.

Comment: In reply to "Does this answer your question?", proclamation 9993 answers my question.

Comment: The last country banned by the US was Brazil and that was two months ago. Since then numerous countries have had an explosion of cases but they weren't added to the travel ban, i.e. you can still travel to the US from Mexico by air. So I would say your odds are good, I did it myself recently.

Comment: @Nzall Cry me a river; "where you're from" has nothing to do with it, only where you've spent the past 14 days

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, according to [Proclamation 9993](https://www.whitehouse.gov/presidential-actions/proclamation-suspension-entry-immigrants-nonimmigrants-certain-additional-persons-pose-risk-transmitting-2019-novel-coronavirus/), there are exceptions to the travel ban for:

> (...)

> (iii)   any alien who is the parent or legal guardian of a U.S. citizen or lawful permanent resident, provided that the U.S. citizen or lawful permanent resident is unmarried and under the age of 21;

> (...)

Note however that it seems you may need to have ample justification of this, including your daughter’s passport or other proof of US citizenship, and proof of her being your daughter (a birth certificate, probably).

Some ESTAs and visas may have been cancelled so you may need a new one.

Some US embassies advise you to contact them before departure.

You should probably **check with your local US embassy or consulate for any special procedure or advice**. There are lots of horror stories out there.