# Can B2 visa holders leave and reenter the US right now?

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas, us-visa

I'm on a B2 visitor visa in the US. I want to go back go the UK for christmas. If I did so would I be able to reenter the country right now? Or would I be denied entry?

Comment: AFAIK the US is allowing B1/B2 visa holders to enter the country by air.  There may or may not be restrictions/isolation etc. requirements in the state after you enter.  B1/B2 visa holders cannot currently enter the US by land.

Comment: Remember that the answers to these sorts of question can change quickly. Christmas is a long time away, and no one today knows what things will be like then.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the current travel restrictions on individuals entering the United States from regions affected by Covid-19?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/153131/what-are-the-current-travel-restrictions-on-individuals-entering-the-united-stat)

Comment: Are you residing in the US on a tourist visa?

Comment: Covid aside, Christmas is 4 months away. How long will you have been in the US by the time you leave? Unless your B2 was explicitly granted for a long stay, I would say there is a danger that you will not be readmitted anyway.

Answer (score 3):

B2 visitors can enter the US right now by air. However, you cannot enter the US if you were physically present in Mainland China, Iran, the Schengen Area, the UK, Ireland, or Brazil in the preceding 14 days.

Comment: Which means that if the rules don’t change until then, OP won’t be able to re-enter the US after having been in the UK, unless they spend at least 14 days in a country not on the blacklist.

Comment: Also note that it seems that many visas have been automatically cancelled. OP should approach the US embassy to confirm status.

Comment: @jcaron: I don't know if you are talking about other countries, but AFAIK no US visas have been "automatically cancelled" other than for overstay.

Comment: @jcaron ESTAs are being automatically cancelled when people try to use them, but [ESTA is not a visa](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/frequently-asked-questions-about-visa-waiver-program-vwp-and-electronic-system-travel).