# During this travel ban (COVID) can my wife come visit me in the USA? I know I can visit there but not sure about her coming here

Tags: international-travel, us-citizens, covid-19

She is dutch and I am a US citizen. Her immigrant visa case is in the process and applied for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the current travel restrictions on individuals entering the United States from regions affected by Covid-19?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/153131/what-are-the-current-travel-restrictions-on-individuals-entering-the-united-stat)