# Travelling to the US via London transit during Covid

Tags: usa, transit, covid-19, f1-visas

I'm an F-1 OPT visa holder who has to visit my home country because of unavoidable personal reasons. Can I enter back into the US via London transit considering the Presidential Proclamation travel restriction?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the current travel restrictions on individuals entering the United States from regions affected by Covid-19?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/153131/what-are-the-current-travel-restrictions-on-individuals-entering-the-united-stat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm an F-1 OPT visa holder. Can I enter back into the US via London transit considering the Presidential Proclamation travel restriction?

Yes since you're F1.

Source: https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php