# Can a green card holder travel to Iran and come back to the US right now?

Tags: international-travel, iran, iranian-citizens, us-permanent-residents

My wife is a green card holder and she wants to travel to Iran in the next month for a couple of weeks. Is she exempt from current 14 days quarantine rule before entering the US?

Comment: "Is she exempt from current 14 days quarantine rule?" There is currently no nationwide quarantine rule in the US. Some states or counties have their own quarantine rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current list of US travel restrictions related to COVID-19 can be found [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/153132/36462). By the "14 day quarantine rule" I assume you are talking about the Presidential Proclamations that require most people who are present in certain affected countries to spend 14 days in some third country before being allowed to enter the US. As mentioned in the linked page, green card holders are exempt from these proclamations, and thus do not need to spend 14 days in a third country after visiting Iran. There is still a COVID-19 testing requirement, however.

Comment: I think I heard that New York State did away with its testing requirement (for those arriving from outside the region) on April 1st, but I'm not planning to travel outside the state in the near future so I didn't pay much attention and I might have misunderstood.  Whatever requirements the US may have for arriving international travelers, one must also take into account additional requirements that may be imposed by states or municipalities.

Comment: +1 This answer is practically also correct. My wife came to Iran and back to the US without any need to remain in a third country by showing her negative COVID-19 test.