# As a Green Card holder, can I travel to Iran and come back to the US without restriction?

Tags: covid-19, iran, us-residents

I am a green card holder and live/work in the US. I want to travel to Iran in July 2021 for a couple of weeks. Am I still exempt from the 14 days quarantine rule in a third country (based on the new [restrictions](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/covid-19-travel-restrictions-and-exceptions.html?fbclid=IwAR3F6LHHWL9iJ3S3Ogxyvp56BMePYiKqrhCVi0Gt3QOax131-ZClwNicMc0)) before entering the US?

Comment: You will have trouble explain to immigration officer why you go to Iran. Be prepared.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a green card holder travel to Iran and come back to the US right now?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/162339/can-a-green-card-holder-travel-to-iran-and-come-back-to-the-us-right-now)

Comment: Dupe: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/162339/29447