# About visa transit lisbon Portugal/ usa

Tags: visas, transit

I am a Moroccan citizen who wants to fly from Morocco to Costa Rica.  Most of the flights are 2 stops.  Can I have a transit visa in Lisbon Portugal, and transit in the USA?

Answer (score 1):

Citizens of Morocco do not need airport transit visas in Portugal or in any other Schengen country.  Therefore:

- If you can change planes in Lisbon without leaving the international area of the airport, you do not need a visa.  If you need to go through passport control, you need a regular short-stay Schengen visa (type C).  If you already have a visa that will be valid at the time of your trip, you can use it even if it was issued by another country.

Citizens of Morocco do need visas to enter our transit the US.  Therefore:

- To transit in the US, you need a visa.  You can apply for a C-1 transit visa or a B-2 visitor visa.  The application fee is the same.  The B-2 visitor visa gives you more flexibility, but the chance of the application being successful may be slightly greater with the C-1 transit visa.

As helpfully pointed out in a comment, however, the current COVID-19 restrictions in the US preclude this itinerary for most people because entry to the US is restricted for people arriving from the Schengen area.  There are several exceptions, but they all seem very unlikely to apply to you.

Comment: Note additionally that, currently, due to covid-19 regulations, [individuals who have been recently physically present in the Schengen area usually may not enter the USA](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/153131/what-are-the-current-travel-restrictions-on-individuals-entering-the-united-stat). This applies even though the time in the Schengen area and the proposed time in the US are both quite short.

Comment: @mlc thanks, I didn't think of that.