# Authoritative website listing the COVID19 banned countries for entry into the US

Tags: usa, covid-19

## Please consider taking action (vote below) to re-open the question

As good as the [community wiki is regarding the subject matter](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/153132/45773), it is NOT authoritative (issued by the authorities).  As such this question stands on its own is not duplicative of said community wiki.  Please consider taking action (vote) below) to re-open the question.

On January 25, the Whitehouse issued a [Proclamation on the Suspension of Entry as Immigrants and Non-Immigrants of Certain Additional Persons Who Pose a Risk of Transmitting Coronavirus Disease](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/presidential-actions/2021/01/25/proclamation-on-the-suspension-of-entry-as-immigrants-and-non-immigrants-of-certain-additional-persons-who-pose-a-risk-of-transmitting-coronavirus-disease/):

> Section 1.  Suspension and Limitation on Entry.  (a)  The entry into
> the United States, as immigrants or nonimmigrants, of noncitizens who
> were physically present within the Schengen Area, the United Kingdom
> (excluding overseas territories outside of Europe), the Republic of
> Ireland, and the Federative Republic of Brazil during the 14-day
> period preceding their entry or attempted entry into the United
> States, is hereby suspended and limited subject to section 2 of this
> proclamation. (b)  The entry into the United States, as immigrants or
> nonimmigrants, of noncitizens who were physically present within the
> Republic of South Africa during the 14-day period preceding their
> entry or attempted entry into the United States, is hereby suspended
> and limited subject to section 2 of this proclamation.

Thus effectively prevent Dutch (Netherlands) nationals from entry.  This will obviously not be permanent:

1. How does one access the regularly updated list of COVID19 banned
   countries?
2. Is there a .gov website that is kept current, that enables European travelers to confirm that they can travel to the USA?

UPDATE:

https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/News/visas-news.html

Comment: This CDC site contains a date when it was last updated (presently 2021-04-30): [Travelers Prohibited from Entry to the United States | CDC](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/from-other-countries.html)

Comment: ... or rather confirm that they can’t, at the moment (unless part of one of the limited exemption classes, of course).