# Can a Russian citizen with a US F1 visa transit at an EU airport?

Tags: usa, schengen, transit, covid-19, russian-citizens

I am a Russian citizen planning to travel to the US in August 2021. Could anyone please advise through which countries I am allowed to fly to the US currently? I have a US F1 visa.
May I travel through European countries if I don't have an EU visa? By "travel through" I mean transit by air.
Do I need to be vaccinated or is a PCR Covid 19 test enough?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What research have you done so far? https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/apply_for_a_visa_en Does ‘travel through’ mean you intend to transit airside or will you need to clear Immigration on arrival in the Schengen area?

Comment: Are you a US permanent resident, or do you have a relationship (spouse, parent, child...) of a US citizen or permanent resident, or are you otherwise [exempted from the US travel bans](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/covid-19-travel-restrictions-and-exceptions.html)? If not, you cannot transit to the US via countries of the Schengen Area, the UK or Ireland, even if you stay airside.

Comment: See our [FAQ on covid-19-related travel restrictions to the US](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/153131/what-are-the-current-travel-restrictions-on-individuals-entering-the-united-stat), but do note that this is a particularly volatile time for many of these restrictions, and it's impossible to predict what might change in the next month or two between now and your proposed flights.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.