# Is there still a way you can get into the US as an international traveller without Covid vaccination?

Tags: usa, covid-19

I am wondering if there is still some way to enter the US without a vaccine passport as an international traveller. (UK-based)
To give a bit of context, I can not take the jab because of religious reasons.
However, I still would like to be able to visit my friends and family now and then in the US.

**Note**: this is a practical question. Let's try to keep it non-political.

Comment: I'd still be curious to understand what "religious reasons" could prevent you from being vaccinated. Most of the alleged reasons some have brandished have turned out to be untrue.

Comment: @jcaron, dont know if its true but I heard some vaccines had gelatin or something so muslims couldnt take them. Not sure if thats true tho

Comment: @bob [some (non-Covid-19) vaccines contain pork gelatin](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/933552/Vaccines_porcine_gelatine_2020_A4.pdf), but [neither of the Covid-19 vaccines in use in the UK contains any](https://fullfact.org/health/there-isnt-pork-in-covid-19-vaccines/).

Comment: Well, it looks like you will have to accept that choosing to belong to a religion that opposes vaccination will limit seriously your options for travel. That is the price you pay for your faith I guess.

Comment: @jcaron One reason could be the use of human embryonic cells from aborted foetuses in vaccine development, which has been controversial for some faiths https://theconversation.com/cells-from-human-foetuses-are-important-for-developing-vaccines-but-theyre-not-an-ingredient-157484 I guess we all have to make choices in many aspects of life, and to accept that those choices may have undesired consequences.

Comment: @Traveller It is worth noting that the Pfizer and Moderna vaccines do not contain, and have not used during the design and development phase, any aborted fetal cells.

Comment: Rules change drastically on Nov 8. Still the answer to this question will be "no" unless you qualify for an exemption. You can check eligibility here: https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/international-travel/travel-assessment/index.html

Comment: Downvoters: even if you disagree with this user's reason for not being vaccinated, the question is a good one.  There will be people who choose not to receive the vaccine or who cannot receive it, and the purpose of this site is not to sit in judgment of their choices or other circumstances but to document the implications for travel.  I suppose if you truly believe that there is no valid reason for any adult not to be vaccinated, then a downvote arguably makes sense, but otherwise, this question is useful for those who do have a valid reason.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the answer is a definite **no** after reading [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/153131/what-are-the-current-travel-restrictions-on-individuals-entering-the-united-stat/153132#153132) extensive Stackexchange answer.