# can a child enter the US by land without full covid vaccination?

Tags: usa, covid-19, borders

I'm looking to travel overland from Canada to US for 3-day visit, with my 8 year old daughter. We're not US citizens or residents.
According [this DHS page](https://www.dhs.gov/news/2021/10/29/fact-sheet-guidance-travelers-enter-us-land-ports-entry-and-ferry-terminals), all travellers 2 years and older are required to be fully vaccinated to enter the US by land. The requirements for air travel are similar and are given [here](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/proof-of-vaccination.html#faq-exceptions); they list some exceptions, including children under 18. For a child who is not fully vaccinated (such as my daughter), it seems that a parent must sign an attestation stating that the child will be tested 3-5 days after entry, then isolate if the test is positive.
I have several questions:

- Does the exception for children also apply for land travel ? Do land travellers also need to sign an attestation?
  **Update**: I've got answers to these questions (**yes** and **no**) from [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/153131/what-are-the-current-travel-restrictions-on-individuals-entering-the-united-stat) (the linked Federal Register document about the US-Canada land border)

I still have this question:

- If we're entering the US for 3 days or less, what am I supposed to do in terms of testing?

Comment: "what am I supposed to do in terms of testing?" - you'll probably never be asked

Comment: Update after the trip: I was asked whether I was vaccinated, but they didn't check my paper very carefully (didn't scan the QR code or anything). No questions about my daughter. Nothing said about post-arrival testing. However, it turns out studded winter tires are illegal in Michigan and several other US states, so I got turned away once at the border and had to rent a car to complete the trip... So lots of hassle, but not what I expected!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We live in Mexico so my experience is from there, but I've crossed the land border into the US at least 26 times in the past year and have never been asked for vaccination info for ourselves or our kids. From my experience you probably won't even be asked.

That said, while looking at the link you included in your question, follow that through to [Frequently Asked Questions](https://www.dhs.gov/news/2021/10/29/frequently-asked-questions-guidance-travelers-enter-us) there is a section that explicitly says that children under 18 are exempt from vaccination requirements.

> ##### Entering the U.S. Through a Land Port of Entry or Ferry Terminal
>
> Q. What are the requirements to enter the United States for children
> under the age of 18 who can't be vaccinated?
>
> A: Children under 18
> years of age are excepted from the vaccination requirement at land and
> ferry POEs.

Comment: +1, no one cares about post-arrival testing in the slightest.